# Debian 11, OpenSSL 1.1.1k, adding and validating self-signed certificate does not work

Tags: debian, openssl, certificates

I'm following [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485511/how-to-run-dotnet-dev-certs-https-trust) to install self-signed certificate. Specifically:

create localhost.conf file with the following content:

```
[req]
default_bits       = 2048
default_keyfile    = localhost.key
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = req_ext
x509_extensions    = v3_ca

[req_distinguished_name]
commonName                  = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default          = localhost
commonName_max              = 64

[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[v3_ca]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
basicConstraints = critical, CA:false
keyUsage = keyCertSign, cRLSign, digitalSignature,keyEncipherment

[alt_names]
DNS.1   = localhost
DNS.2   = 127.0.0.1
```

then:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
$ openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.crt -config localhost.conf -subj '/CN=localhost'
Generating a RSA private key
...+++++
...........................................................+++++
writing new private key to 'localhost.key'
-----
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out localhost.pfx -inkey localhost.key -in localhost.crt
Enter Export Password: (empty password)
Verifying - Enter Export Password: (empty password)
$ sudo cp localhost.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

Adding debian:localhost.pem
done.
done.
$ openssl verify localhost.crt
CN = localhost
error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed certificate
error localhost.crt: verification failed
```

I suppose the latest command should verify the certificate successfully as it should be installed into the CA keys (i.e. trusted), but it does not. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: You may need to re-trace your steps.  I've copied the above verbatim on a Debian 11 box and got `localhost.crt: OK` at the last step, which is what you would expect.

Comment: My box was upgraded from Debian 10. Will try to reinstall it. Thanks!